# Where to find QSettings on macOS

Tags: qt, settings, preferences, qsettings

So I am using `QSettings` to store my preferences, and according to https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#platform-specific-notes there is several locations where this is actually stored.

I am on macOS 10.14, yet I find the settings in `$HOME/Library/Preferences/org.mycomp.myapp.plist` (the above link states this should be for macOS 10.2/10.3).

Now I can see by opening that this file contains my most recent settings changes, however, after deleting, my app still loads the settings. So there must be a second location where it is stored? But I can't seem to find it.

1. $HOME/Library/Preferences/com.MySoft.Star Runner.plist - **non existing**
2. $HOME/Library/Preferences/com.MySoft.plist - **existed, deleted**
3. /Library/Preferences/com.MySoft.Star Runner.plist - **non existing**
4. /Library/Preferences/com.MySoft.plist - **non existing**

And for the **unix** variants:

1. $HOME/.config/MySoft/Star Runner.conf - **non existing**
2. $HOME/.config/MySoft.conf - **non existing**
3. for each directory  in $XDG_CONFIG_DIRS: /MySoft/Star Runner.conf - **non existing**
4. for each directory  in $XDG_CONFIG_DIRS: /MySoft.conf - **non existing**

So where is the settings still saved?!

In my `main.cpp` I have:

```
    QCoreApplication::setOrganizationName("Firstname Lastname");
    QCoreApplication::setOrganizationDomain("mycomp.org");
    QCoreApplication::setApplicationName("MyApp");
```

And I am using `QSettings` with the default constructor. I am using Qt 5.13.2.

Comment: [`QSettings::fileName`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#fileName) should tell you where the file is actually saved to and restored from.

Comment: It gives me `$HOME/Library/Preferences/org.mycomp.myapp.plist` - the file I have already deleted.
According to `lsof` this file is not open, and also does not exist (as I have deleted it, but not yet stored any new settings).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since macOS Mavericks (10.9) preferences are cached to improve performance, so they say. When you delete the .plist file, they are still in memory each time you execute your program. You need to clear the preferences cache with this command:

```
killall -u $USER cfprefsd
```

Or you can reboot your computer...

If you (and your users) are tired of this, you may consider to use INI files with QSettings instead of the native OS format:

```
QSettings("MyApp.ini", QSettings::IniFormat)
```

Comment: Thanks, indeed it felt like some sort of caching. I will try out after work, and approve when its working. Thanks already.

Comment: It worked, however you've got a typo, its actually `cfprefsd`.

Comment: Thanks to you. I've fixed it for the next one looking for the answer.